# retornar el índice de una palabra que contenga ciertos caracteres dentro de un array

Tags: javascript, array, index

Tengo una función que debe devolverme el índice de las palabras derivadas de un string. En el array del ejemplo, estoy buscando la palabra "comprado", y le tengo que pasar como parámetro "compr", de manera que si en vez de "comprado", el array tuviera otra palabra derivada de "compr" como por ejemplo "comprando", también debería darme su índice. El problema es que indexOf() solo me retorna el índice cuando el string es estrictamente igual. Digamos que lo que yo necesito es una especie de contains() o includes() mezclado con indexOf()...

```
function getWord() {
    
    let array = ["hola", "me", "he", "comprado", "un", "coche"];
    let word = "compr";
    let result = 0;
 
     for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      result = array.indexOf(word) //Esto me devuelve -1 porque en el array no encuentra "compr"
     }
     
     return result;   
 }
```

¿Existe alguna función de javascript que me devuelva el indice de una coincidencia como la que expongo?

Gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Deberias [edit] tu pregunta y poner un [example] que se pueda ejecutar, lo que has puesto no sirve para realizar pruebas pues los arrays ya estan mal de saque y en tu ejemplo siguiente tampoco sabemos lo que es _compr_ o _comprado_. Tambien deberias agregar la etiqueta de javascript para darle más visibilidad. Lo que buscas es una combinación de indexOf con una función que en PHP se denomina similar_text, y que si lo buscas por google verás alguna parecida en javascript y podras combinar ambas.

Comment: El método [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) devuelve el índice del primer elemento que coincida con el argumento que pasas a esa función. ¿Porqué intentas asignarle un índice a ese método? Deberías hacerlo con `const indiceBuscado = arr.indexOf("comprado");`. Una lectura de la documentación te haría la vida más sencilla. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras no estoy asignando nada, esa es la salida que me devuelve. Es un ejercicio en el que hago varias cosas, entre ellas, necesito setear el indice de todas las palabras que contengan "compr". he leído la documentación de indexOF y el problema está en que si paso por parámetro "compr", no la encuentra, por eso devuelve -1. Yo necesito que al pasarle "compr", me devuelva el índice de comprado, compré y comprando.

Comment: @masterguru ya está editada. Espero haberme explicado mejor ahora. mi intención era ser lo más concreto posible. Disculpen las molestias.

Comment: @InfiniteRoads gracias por el intento, pero sigue sin ser un [example].  Haz una cosa para solucionarlo que además te irá muy bien para depurar en javascript.  Vete a https://jsfiddle.net/ y pega ese código en la casilla del javascript, y dale al botón RUN de arriba a la izquierda.  Y verás que da errores de interpretación. Los arreglas y cuando consigas que el ejemplo te funcione sin errores de sintaxis coges y lo pegas aquí para que podamos ayudarte.  Es lo que hago yo siempre que veo preguntas de javascript para intentar ayudar, y si me dan errores de sintaxis pues me dan trabajo de más.

Comment: Para ver esos errores de sintaxis debes ver la consola, claro, que está debajo de el recuadro blanco que es para la salida HTML del script, donde a su pie veras qeu pone "Console(beta)"... pulsas alli y te aparecerá una consola con la que puedes depurar tu codigo. Para ello debes usar un console.log() claro, de tu funcion.

Comment: @masterguru Vale! Muchas gracias! Ahora ya si funciona el ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo que necesitas es esto:

```js
let array = ["hola", "me", "he", "comprado", "un", "coche", "comprimido"];
let word = "compr";

let indexMatches = []
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i].includes(word) == true) {
    indexMatches.push(i)
  }
}
console.log(indexMatches)
```

De esta forma recorres el array y allí donde encuentre ese trozo de texto (mediante [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)) agregará su índice en el array **indexMatches** que luego mostramos en consola.

Comment: Sí, sabía que por ahí iban los tiros pero necesitaba confirmar. Muchísimas gracias!!